# jQuery - Auto play in concrete slideshow

Tags: jquery, function, playback

I have a problem with auto play and when slides go to the end I would like to go to first again, in this slide show:

[jQuery Slideshow](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/)

I tried to use this function, but this not help me:

```
$('#slideshow').slide({
    extend: function() {
        this.play(1000);
    }
});
```

and also:

```
setInterval( function(){ ... }, 3000);
```

Thanks all for help

Comment: Have you tried the modified version in the comments of this page? http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/#comment-40273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have studied some of your code on controls class you have binded the click event. So by taking code from it adding it to function and then calling it after some interval will make the slider work automatically. Code will be something like this:

```
function slideme(position)
{
    currentPosition = (position=='right') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
    // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);
    // Move slideInner using margin-left
    $('#slideInner').animate({
        'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
    });
}

//on document ready
$(function(){               
        slideme('left');
        //Add Some intervals
        slideme('left');
        //Add Some intervals
        slideme('left');
        //Add Some intervals
        slideme('left');
        //Add Some intervals
        slideme('right');

        //all above you can write in loops by getting total no of slides dynamically        
});
```